# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException ikaOnDotNet.MySystemClassLoader

Tags: java, c#, apache-tika

I Installed the nuget package for TikaOnDotNet and trying to run this : `var textExtractionResult = new TextExtractor().Extract(new Uri(url));`
But I am getting this error:
[image]

It looks like Java class loader issue and i have this code in my Global.asax:

```
public class MySystemClassLoader : ClassLoader
    {
        public MySystemClassLoader(ClassLoader parent)
            : base(new AppDomainAssemblyClassLoader(typeof(MySystemClassLoader).Assembly))
        {
        }
    }
```

What am i missing?!

Comment: Do you try google? This may help you: http://clarify.dovetailsoftware.com/kmiller/2010/07/02/using-the-tika-java-library-in-your-net-application-with-ikvm/

Comment: @csharpfolk I looked into that article and also of course I googled it.
I asked the question after spending few hours somewhere else looking for an answer

Comment: The GitHub Issue for this problem is https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet/issues/15